# When copying files via USB from Ubuntu to Windows 7, there is a different number of files

Tags: filesystem, files, hidden-files

What's up guys, I'm trying to backup some Ubuntu files to my Windows machine. I have all the files in one folder and when I click "Properties" in Ubuntu it says 696 items, 742.6 MB. When I copied that SAME folder over to Windows it shows as 687 Files, 88 Folders and 708 MB. What's the difference here? I'm assuming one is counting folders and files differently, but the numbers still don't add up. Is there anyway to account for this difference?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is . . . hidden dot files( the ones that have leading dot in the name, e.g. `.file1.txt` ). They are included in the total count of files and folder size , but are not shown by default. Observe the example bellow: I've a folder `/home/xieerqi/EXAMPLE` where I copied contents of my `/etc/passwd` file. In the properties you can see total count of two, but without `.test1` being shown , you will only see `test2`.

[image]

What you want to do is open file manager's  <kbd>View</kbd> menu and ensure `Show Hidden Files` is checked, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to have the same effect. Alternatively , if you are not shy of using command line, you can use `rsync -a SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR`

```
 rsync -a /home/user/Pictures /media/user/usb_drive
```

Comment: Alright thanks that must be it. So Windows doesn't even count them at all then? Are those hidden dot files necessary for anything? I'm assuming it's extras like thumbnails or something

Comment: @noobasaurus they are settings/configuration files. They are sort of important. What's your goal in copying the directory ? System backup ?

Comment: yea, just wanna back up the files and reformat my ubuntu machine and then copy them back. The files themselves are the most important

Comment: OK. So depending on whether or not you want just your personal data or personal data plus your settings , you may or may not want to keep those files. Read up on [What's a good backup strategy](http://askubuntu.com/q/569679/295286), and give an upvote to that post and some of the answers if you find those useful